# Retrieving multiple rows from database

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I have an assignedset table where there are two rows. I want to retrieve the set_number from the two rows which are 1 and 3. My codes are below, right now it retrieves 3 and 3 which is incorrect. Can anyone help me with this?

```
MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("Select set_number from assignedset where patient_nric='" + NRIC + "'", myConn);

MySqlDataReader myReader;
myConn.Open();
myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
int count = 0;
while (myReader.Read())
{
  count = count + 1;
}
if (count > 0)
{
  string SetName = myReader.GetString("set_number");
  //int[] numbers;
  int s = 1;
  while (s <= count)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(SetName);
    s++;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (myReader.Read())
{
  count = count + 1;
}

if (count > 0)
{
  string SetName = myReader.GetString("set_number");      
  ...
```

In you code, you only get the set_number from your last row.

Try the following.

```
while (myReader.Read())
{
  string SetName = myReader.GetString("set_number");
  MessageBox.Show(SetName);
  count = count + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Logic error.

```
while (myReader.Read())
```

is use for reading each row of data from your data set.

And yet you show the result --> MessageBox.Show(SetName);
after the myReader.Read() loop has been done, of course you will forever get the last result, which is "3" in your case.

You should do something as below:
have a try

```
if (myReader.HasRows)
{
    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        string SetName = myReader.GetString("set_number");
        MessageBox.Show(SetName);
    }
}
```